# How to extend String Prototype and use it next, in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am extending String prototype chain with a new method but when I try to use it it throws me an error: `property 'padZero' does not exist on type 'string'`. Could anyone solve this for me?

The code is below. You can also see the same error in Typescript Playground.

```
interface NumberConstructor {
    padZero(length: number);
}
interface StringConstructor {
    padZero(length: number): string;
}
String.padZero = (length: number) => {
    var s = this;
    while (s.length < length) {
      s = '0' + s;
    }
    return s;
};
Number.padZero = function (length) {
    return String(this).padZero(length);
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you want to augment the `class`, and not the `instance`, augment the constructor:

```js
declare global {
  interface StringConstructor {
    padZero(s: string, length: number): string;
  }
}

String.padZero = (s: string, length: number) => {
  while (s.length < length) {
    s = '0' + s;
  }
  return s;
};

console.log(String.padZero('hi', 5))

export {}
```

*The empty export on the bottom is required if you `declare global` in `.ts` and do not export anything.  This forces the file to be a module. *

If you want the function on the `instance` (aka `prototype`),

```js
declare global {
  interface String {
    padZero(length: number): string;
  }
}

String.prototype.padZero = function (length: number) {
  let d = String(this)
  while (d.length < length) {
    d = '0' + d;
  }
  return d;
};

console.log('hi'.padZero(5))

export {}
```

Comment: I've done the second option, but for some reason at runtime I still get isNullOrEmpty is not a function.

Comment: thats not a typescript issue then. you should debug to see what runtime type it is.

Comment: Managed to figure out my mistake: I augmented the instance, which is kind of pointless when you're trying to test for Null OR Empty considering if the variable is null you'll end up with the exception I had. I changed it to augmenting the class which solved my issue. Thanks for the insight in your answer.

Comment: It is so sad that such a poorly designed language has gained so much popularity...

Comment: It is so sad that you didn't take the time to understand the design choices in the language.

Comment: In my experiments, putting `declare global` produces a compile error -- "Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.ts".  Is this still possible to enhance String, without having to import something every time?

Comment: used this in 4.3.5 and now trying to use it in 4.6.2 and for some reason, there are issues.

Comment: @AdamArold, that's not a fair comment, at all. Similar "design choices" in other languages like extending basic type functionality are straight-forward, and just...work. Look up the meaning of a Hobsian choice.

Comment: pishpish @toddmo What other languages? Python monkey patching works the exact same way, but has no way to extend typing information for mypy

Answer (score 152):

This answer applies to TypeScript 1.8+. There are lots of other answers to this sort of question, but they all seem to cover older versions.

There are two parts to extending a prototype in TypeScript.

### Part 1 - Declare

Declaring the new member so it can pass type-checking. You need to declare an interface with the same name as the constructor/class you want to modify and put it under the correct declared namespace/module. This is called *scope augmentation*.

Extending the modules in this way can only be done in a special declaration `.d.ts` files*.

```
//in a .d.ts file:
declare global {
    interface String {
        padZero(length : number) : string;
    }
}
```

Types in external modules have names that include quotation marks, such as `"bluebird"`.

The module name for global types such as `Array<T>` and `String` is `global`, without any quotes. However, in many versions of TypeScript you can forego the module declaration completely and declare an interface directly, to have something like:

```
declare interface String {
        padZero(length : number) : string;
}
```

This is the case in some versions pre-1.8, and also some versions post-2.0, such as the most recent version, 2.5.

Note that you cannot have anything except `declare` statements in the `.d.ts` file, otherwise it won't work.

These declarations are added to the ambient scope of your package, so they will apply in all TypeScript files even if you never `import` or `///<reference` the file directly. However, you still need to import the implementation you write in the 2nd part, and if you forget to do this, you'll run into runtime errors.

* Technically you can get past this restriction and put declarations in regular `.ts` files, but this results in some finicky behavior by the compiler, and it's not recommended.

### Part 2 - Implement

Part 2 is actually implementing the member and adding it to the object it should exist on like you would do in JavaScript.

```
String.prototype.padZero = function (this : string, length: number) {
    var s = this;
    while (s.length < length) {
      s = '0' + s;
    }
    return s;
};
```

Note a few things:

1. `String.prototype` instead of just `String`, which is the `String` constructor, rather than its prototype.
2. I use an explicit `function` instead of an arrow function, because a `function` will correctly receive the `this` parameter from where it's invoked. An arrow function will always use the same `this` as the place it's declared in. The one time we don't want that to happen is when extending a prototype.
3. The explicit `this`, so the compiler knows the type of `this` we expect. This part is only available in TS 2.0+. Remove the `this` annotation if you're compiling for 1.8-. Without an annotation, `this` may be implicitly typed `any`.

### Import the JavaScript

In TypeScript, the `declare` construct adds members to the ambient scope, which means they appear in all files. To make sure your implementation from part 2 is hooked up, `import` the file right at the start of your application.

You import the file as follows:

```
import '/path/to/implementation/file';
```

Without importing anything. You can also import something from the file, but you don't need to import the function you defined on the prototype.

Comment: I am using v2.1.0-dev.20161001. I tried this before, but it gives me the error above in `declare global` too. Also, I noticed a lot of answers from stackoverflow tell us to extend without prototype but the code generated doesn't use it... what is the catch here? Why is this so hard?

Comment: That's not the main thing wrong in your code above. The main thing is that you're extending the constructor, not the prototype. If you wrote something else, then update the code in the question.

Comment: This works when I try it in a local project, but it doesn't work in Angular. Could Angular be overwriting the String again or something...?

Comment: **Ambient Scope** was the issue for me - great catch! I had to import the prototype into the TS files I wanted to use the extensions in, it didn't use to work that way in earlier versions of TS

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in an Angular project, saying the method is not defined on String. if you have some extra tips on how to get this to work in an Angular project, please let us know.

Comment: this example is somewhat confusing and could be better if it were shown as complete.  The import is specifically confusing.  Do you declare the variable again? Or are you referencing the `declare` from part 1

Comment: also, if you try to put it in a `.d.ts` file in 2.5.1 you get the following error: `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.`

Comment: also, also... there is no export in part 2 of your example?  how do you import the function?

Comment: @NSjonas I can't reproduce that in 2.5.3. Maybe you have other stuff in the `.d.ts` file besides `declare` statements? There is no need to export anything. All you need to do is execute the code inside the implementation file. I made that a bit clearer.

Comment: @GregRos Yea, I had other stuff in my `.d.ts` file. I put it in the root `types.d.ts` and it seems to work without the declare.  Thanks for clarifying the import.

Comment: Hey this is a great answer, I was wondering if you know of any way to modify a global interface in a non-ambient context?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If the type declarations are inside a package, only an application that `import`s the package will be able to see them. Other than that, there isn't really a way to do it directly. But maybe there are alternatives. Open a question and explain what you mean.

Comment: is there a way to wire it up without import the implementation file?

Answer (score 29):

Here is a working example, a simple Camel Case string modifier.

in my ***index.d.ts*** for my project

```
interface String {
    toCamelCase(): string;
}
```

in my root `.ts` somewhere accessible

```
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function(): string { 
    return this.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|-|\b\w)/g, 
       (ltr, idx) => idx === 0
              ? ltr.toLowerCase()
              : ltr.toUpperCase()
    ).replace(/\s+|-/g, '');
};
```

That was all I needed to do to get it working in typescript `^2.0.10`.

I use it like `str.toCamelCase()`

**update**

I realized I had this need too and this is what I had

```
interface String {
    leadingChars(chars: string|number, length: number): string;
}


String.prototype.leadingChars = function (chars: string|number, length: number): string  {
    return (chars.toString().repeat(length) + this).substr(-length);
};
```

so `console.log('1214'.leadingChars('0', 10));` gets me `0000001214`

Answer (score 27):

For me the following worked in an Angular 6 project using TypeScript 2.8.4.

In the typings.d.ts file add:

```
interface Number {
  padZero(length: number);
}

interface String {
  padZero(length: number);
}
```

Note: No need to 'declare global'.

In a new file called string.extensions.ts add the following:

```
interface Number {
  padZero(length: number);
}

interface String {
  padZero(length: number);
}

String.prototype.padZero = function (length: number) {
  var s: string = String(this);
  while (s.length < length) {
    s = '0' + s;
  }
  return s;
}

Number.prototype.padZero = function (length: number) {
  return String(this).padZero(length)
}
```

To use it, first import it:

```
import '../../string.extensions';
```

Obviously your import statement should point to the correct path.
Inside your class's constructor or any method:

```
var num: number = 7;
var str: string = "7";
console.log("padded number: ", num.padZero(5));
console.log("padding string: ", str.padZero(5));
```

Comment: The only answer that works for Node.JS, TypeScript 3.3.1

Comment: Can you kindly explain how to use typing.d.ts file?

Comment: If your file uses `import`s your interface will implictly become module-scoped, so `declare global`will be required.

Answer (score 8):

### 2022 typescript 4.9

The solution is pretty simple but getting to that solution was not. Ignore the top voted answer; most of that isn't needed and doesn't work any more.

**index.d.ts**

Not needed!

**strings.ts**

```
interface String {
    toProperCase(): string;
    bool(): boolean;
}

String.prototype.toProperCase = function (): string {
    return this.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, (c: string) => c.toUpperCase())
}

String.prototype.bool = function (): boolean {
    return this.toLowerCase() == 'true';
};
```

**using it**

```
import './lib/strings'

var a = 'hello'
var b = a.toProperCase()
```

outputs:

> Hello

Comment: If we have some import (let's say helper function for logging) on top of `interface String` in `strings.ts`. TypeScript gives the error `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'String' `. @toddmo do you have any clue how to resolve this?

Comment: @JDSolanki, your interface statements need to come first in the file for the compiler. Import statements can go lower and don't need to be on top. They only need to be above where they are used.

Comment: @toddmo Unfortunately with `import` in between interface and String.prototype it simply doesn't work for me, always `property does not exist on type`

Comment: is this anywhere to guarantee these extension methods are always imported without needing an import line?

Answer (score 2):

A slight modification on toddmo's answer: I needed to declare the interface via `declare global {}`:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        repeatAction: (action: (str: string) => string) => string;
    }
}

String.prototype.repeatAction = function(this: string, action: (str: string) => string) {
    let str = this;
    do {
        var tempStr = str;
        str = action(str);
    } while (tempStr != str);

    return str;
};
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and [Steven's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53392268/3997521)?