# Ionic2 add custom extension method

Tags: angular, ionic2, extension-methods

I want to add extension method to native String type.

string-extension.ts:

```
interface String {
    toSlug(): string;
}

String.prototype.toSlug = function () {
    var str = this.toLowerCase();
    str = str.replace(/à|á|ạ|ả|ã|â|ầ|ấ|ậ|ẩ|ẫ|ă|ằ|ắ  |ặ|ẳ|ẵ/g, "a");
    str = str.replace(/è|é|ẹ|ẻ|ẽ|ê|ề|ế|ệ|ể|ễ/g, "e");
    str = str.replace(/ì|í|ị|ỉ|ĩ/g, "i");
    str = str.replace(/ò|ó|ọ|ỏ|õ|ô|ồ|ố|ộ|ổ|ỗ|ơ|ờ|ớ  |ợ|ở|ỡ/g, "o");
    str = str.replace(/ù|ú|ụ|ủ|ũ|ư|ừ|ứ|ự|ử|ữ/g, "u");
    str = str.replace(/ỳ|ý|ỵ|ỷ|ỹ/g, "y");
    str = str.replace(/đ/g, "d");
    str = str.replace(/!|@|%|\^|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\<|\>|\?|\/|,|\.|\:|\;|\'| |\"|\&|\#|\[|\]|~|$|_/g, " ");
    str = str.replace(/-+-/g, " ");
    str = str.replace(/^\-+|\-+$/g, "");
    return str.trim();
}
```

Usage:

```
public slug: string = "UTF String".toSlug();
```

VS Code suggestion works fine without any problem. However after `ionic serve` it throws `String.toSlug is not a function`

Following is my CLI version:

`Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.13
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.1`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you share the code where it is imported and used?

Comment: Ionic build/serve auto import any *.ts file in src directory. I found this line in `tsconfig.js` : `"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript

Comment: tried the solutions here?

Comment: Thank you. The solution above does not work but i found problem is ionic-app-script module did not include string.ts when compiling. It works if i import string.ts inside controller `import '../../extensions/string.ts`

Comment: can you add the solution? Thanks

Comment: @SurajRao I did. Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Solution is import extension files into `app.module.ts`:

```
import '../extentions/string.ts';
import '../extensions/array.ts';
...
```

Change prototype into this (angular 2+):

```
String.prototype.toSlug = function (this:string) { ... }
```

Problem is ionic-app-script module does not include files while compiling.