# Convert Javascript to Typescript when modifying a function through the variable reference

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert a javascript code file to a typescript file, however, I have difficulties doing it when meeting to modify a function through the variable reference.

In javascript, the code was written as:

```
  Object.getPrototypeOf(ctx).rounded_rect = function(){

  }
```

where `ctx` is a canvas rendering context 2d varibale

How do I convert this code to typescript code? When I copy and paste it to typescript file, it shows error saying `Property 'rounded_rect' does not exist on type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.`

Also, what is this line of code called?

Comment: Whats ctx? .....

Comment: @Jonasw a Canva Context2D variable

Comment: So you want to extend the native `CanvasRenderingContext2D` by adding `rounded_rect` method?

Comment: @pawel yeah I guess so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the native prototype which requires a declaration first:

```
declare global {
   interface  CanvasRenderingContext2D {
      rounded_rect() : void;
   }
}
```

After that you can implement it:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.rounded_rect = function(){
 /*whatever*/
};
```

May refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript)  similar answer...