# Can`t extend the JavaScript native method declaration when use TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to extend JS native String class adding the new method but get TS2339 error.

```
interface String {
  transl(): string;
}

String.prototype.transl = function() { // TS2339: Property 'transl' does not exist on type 'String'.
  return 'xxx';
};

'ff'.transl();
```

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is technically correct, and works in the TypeScript playground, which leads me to believe that the problem is being caused by having this code inside of a module.

When you write an interface within a module, or namespace, it contributes to the naming context of that module or namespace. i.e. you may well be adding a new interface named `String` to your local naming context, rather than merging your interface declaration with the global `String` interface.

You can fix this by placing your interface in the global context, so it has the same common root as the one from the `lib.d.ts` file. Or using `declare global` *from within a module*:

```
declare global {
  interface String {
    transl(): string;
  }
}

String.prototype.transl = function () {
  return 'xxx';
};

'ff'.transl();
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to specifically mention [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) and how to do it in this case?