# How to import a library in a TypeScript file that extends a JavaScript prototype

Tags: typescript, import, momentjs, prototype

Using the techniques described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript), I am attempting to use Moment.js to extend the `Date` prototype in a TypeScript project.

Extending the `Date` prototype works, as described:

```
interface Date {
    myExtension: () => string;
}

if (!Date.prototype.myExtension) {
    Date.prototype.myExtension = function(): string {
        return 'some value derived from a date';
    };
}
```

However, as soon as I import Moment.js, by adding the following line to my file, TypeScript invalidates my code, telling me that `Property 'myExtension' does not exist on type 'Date'`.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Is there another way I should be declaring the Moment.js import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, how `moment` relates to your question - I assume here, that you want to add global types to `Date.prototype`, that will be internally implemented by `moment`.

You can  augment a [global type definition](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html) of a built-in type `Date` by defining the types 1.) in their own `.d.ts` file or 2.) in one of your existent [file modules](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/modules.html#file-module).

**1. global declaration  file**

Create `global.d.ts` (naming doesn't matter). Put `Date` interface in it, which will be [merged](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) with the already existent Date interface from `lib.d.ts`. Make sure, you do not have any top level `export` or `import` declarations in it to append types to the global namespace/scope. `global.d.ts` will be automatically included in projects with a `tsconfig.json`.

```
// global.d.ts:
interface Date {
  myExtension: () => string;
}
```

**2. file module**

Wrap the definitions in a global context with `declare global`:

```
// inside some file module with export/import
...
declare global {
  interface Date {
    myExtension: () => string;
  }
}
```

Test it in App.ts

```
// use moment for implementation
import * as moment from "moment"; 

if (!Date.prototype.myExtension) {
  Date.prototype.myExtension = function(): string {
    return "some value derived from a date";
  };
}

const d = new Date();
console.log(d.myExtension()); // some value derived from a date
```

Comment: Thank you for a very clear explanation. Essentially, my mistake was not declaring my interface global within my implementation file. Once I added this, the error went away.