# Wrap all basic types in TypeScript with Macros or pre or post-processor

Tags: typescript

Just wondering if that's possible or maybe someone already tried that. I would like to do extend base JS types without actually extending it.

I **don't want to directly extend prototype** as that would taint the JS runtime. I want to "extend" it without actually extending it.

Possible approach:

Feed `extensions.d.ts` to TS with fake declarations how base types are extended

```
interface String {
  isBlank(): boolean
}
```

Provide wrapper function to JS runtime

```
function w(v: string | Object | ...) {
  if (typeof v == 'string') return new ExtendedString(v)
  ...
}
```

Somehow make TypeScript to pre or post process TypeScript files and turn

```
const s = "Hi"
const list = [1, 2, 3]
const map = { a: 1 }
function send(msg: string) { msg.isBlank() } // Should work
send("Hello")
```

into

```
const s = w("Hi")
const map = w({ a: 1 })
const list = w([1, 2, 3])
function send(msg: string) { msg.isBlank() } // Should work
send(w("Hello"))
```

There's no need for TypeScript to understand how `w` works, it just should blindly wrap with it every object of base type that's being created.

I don't care about native objects leaking from API or created in factory methods etc., as I would use only APIs that's compatible with this approach. Also I don't mind performance drop.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear about the higher-level problem you're trying to solve, because, as a solution, this sounds complicated and is likely to be fragile. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: @spender I want to be able to use `"Some message".isBlank()` or `[1, 2].isEqual([1, 2])` etc. Not `isBlank("Some message")` or `isEqual([1,2], [1, 2])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend String Prototype and use it next, in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript)

Comment: @NicholasTower no, when you extend prototype you taint the runtime. I wondering if it's possible to do that cleanly.

Comment: So you're trying to essentially pre-process your typescript source files to allow you to "extend" everything by transforming the code? We'll you'll probably want to use the compiler API to parse, transform, and emit the new code. Probably write a language service to support your "extended" language. You should [start here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).