# How do I extend a global interface locally in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand [this GitHub post](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9212) that describes extending a global interface locally.

However, since there is minimal commentary in the post, I'm struggling to understand what is going on. Below is the post I am referring to.

> you can extend a global interface locally
>
> ```
> declare global {
>     interface String {
>         myMegaMethod(): void;
>     }
> }    
> 'hey'.myMegaMethod(); // works
> ```

If I was to use the following pattern to extend the functionality of a native type like `String`, how would I do so?

**Do I just have a file called `string.ts` containing the following snippet that I import whenever I want my Strings to have access to `myMegaMethod`?**

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        myMegaMethod(): void;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to modify the `String.prototype` in order to make that method *actually* available. The global interfaces are just to make TS know that this method exists, it doesn't create the method for you,.

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53392268/9590251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm struggling to understand what is going on.

The example code mentioned just shows the how that method can be used and does not talk anything about the complete `implementation` and its `usage`, Also the code is used for [`type declaration`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) aka `d.ts` files for other modules to use and it is one of the step to achieve the goal you mentioned.

Actually to extend the '`string`' you may not even need to `global declare` just a simple interface in new `d.ts` file would work which you can refer in the attached SO link below.

> If I was to use the following pattern to extend the functionality of a
> native type like String, how would I do so?

First of all just adding that code in .ts file `wont` work. There are steps which you need to follow to achieve this mainly using the `prototype`

This is completely described in the below SO thread -

[How to extend String Prototype and use it next, in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript)