# how to make an extension of string in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need to add my own method into a string in typescript. so hopefully I can do something like this

```
const myPoint : string = "23";
const customNumber = myPoint.convertUsingMyCustomImplementation();
```

I try this (using capital S) :

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native
String.prototype.convertUsingMyCustomImplementation = function() : number {
  return parseFloat(this);
};
```

but I have two errors

[image]

> Property 'convertUsingMyCustomImplementation' does not exist on type
> 'String'.
>
> Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string'.   'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object.
> Prefer using 'string' when possible.

and I also try the code below:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native
string.prototype.convertUsingMyCustomImplementation = function() : number {
  return parseFloat(this);
};
```

but I also have an error

[image]

how to achieve that using Typescript?

Comment: What happened when you used `String.prototype` and `String: this` ? Did you try that yet? (I don't use typescript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend String Prototype and use it next, in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prototype method was fine. You just have to declare that string will have this method. Usually you do this in a .d.ts file to allow it to work everywhere, but you can do it in a regular ts file in a pinch.

```
declare global { 
    interface String { 
        convertUsingMyCustomImplementation(): number;
    } 
}
```