# Add a function to a class defined inside a declared namespace (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

I'm trying to add a new function to an existing class `Node` defined inside the namespace `cc`. The namespace is declared as follows:

**creator.d.ts**

```
declare namespace cc {
   ...
   export class Node extends _BaseNode {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

And my extension function attempt looks like:

**NodeExtension.ts**

```
interface cc {
    Node: {
        getWorldPosition(): cc.Vec2;
    }
}
cc.Node.prototype.getWorldPosition = function (this: cc.Node)  {
    return this.parent.convertToWorldSpaceAR(this.getPosition());
};
```

But I'm getting the error "***Property 'getWorldPosition' does not exist on type 'Node'***" when trying to set the function.

The creator.d.ts declaration file belongs to the game development framework Cocos Creator.

Comment: `cc` is namespace or interface? why are the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function to a class inside a namespace by first creating an interface (`Node`) that is wrapped inside a namespace with the same name (`cc`) that is then wrapped inside a `declare global` statement and then by adding the interface method (`getWorldPosition`) to the `.prototype` property of the type you want to extend (`cc.Node`).

## Example

```
declare global
{
    namespace cc
    {
        interface Node
        {
            getWorldPosition(): cc.Vec2;
        }
    }
}

cc.Node.prototype.getWorldPosition = function(this: cc.Node)
{
    return this.parent.convertToWorldSpaceAR(this.getPosition());
};

export {}
```

## Reference

This solution was based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53392268/5946094

Comment: I actually tried that but was having errors. The `export {}` did the trick. Not sure what it does (I'm new to js and ts) but guess I'll have to learn more about it. Thank you for your answer!